# Chef Java API Authentication

Tags: chef-infra

I was trying to hit the Chef API using thebelow REST call for authentication
https://ip-100-00-10-167.us-west-2.compute.internal/organizations/ABCD/authenticate_user?username=chefadmin&password=chefadmin

The response doesnt share any output like Cookie details but the status shows OK 200 as code..

Any insights / thoughts please share

Answer (score 0):

The `authenticate_user` API is special. It's an internal-only API and is not for public use. If you want to do some kind of authentication integration with Chef for some reason, use the oc-id service.

Comment: can you please share details on how to use the chef API to fetch details for getting the nodes / runlists...

Comment: You want the `/node` APIs, as the name implies that is how you get data about nodes. Jclouds includes an API wrapper to access the Chef API from Java.

Comment: https://github.com/charleyw/chef-api-java - just applied the chef-api-java from charley...when accessed the chef https instance, ended up with exception as below.        avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Dear Coderanger...any thoughts to handle this exception

Comment: Whatever TLS certificate your Chef Server is using isn't trusted by Java. If it's self-signed, you need to import it directly. If it's from a public CA, check if the CA root cert is in Java's trust repo and if you are sending the correct chain certs.

Comment: Can you please help with the details of this TSL certificate in Chef instance..i tried using the CA certificate in KeyStore, but didnt help to close this exception.

Comment: No, this is outside the scope of the original question and TLS in Java is both very complex and not my area of expertise. Use the Googles.